# Why does not Opera 9.6 work with Jquery context selector in my code

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector, opera

please help
The jQuery Code:

```
jQuery.ajax({url:nextPortionLink,
             success: function(data) {
               nextPortion = jQuery("#productList", data).html();
             }});
```

Variable `data` has html page with `#productList, .productImage, a, img`...

But any of these selectors doesn't work here. Why?

`jQuery(data).find("anything")` doesn't work either

`nextPortion == null` for Opera 9.6

This code works fine with IE7,8 FF3-4 but not in Opera 9.6 and IE9

Comment: Is the AJAX call returning the correct HTML in `data`?

Comment: it would be nice if you can post a fiddle so we can see what's happening. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

check jQuery's dataType, should be "html":

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url:nextPortionLink,
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
        nextPortion = jQuery("#productList", data).html();
    }
});
```

you must be sure that your jQuery obj is of dataType 'html', if not (OP will return null) you can force it to be 'html' using:

```
var data = jQuery(data).html();
```

find working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/aA3VN/1/

Comment: I have used your suggestion var tmp = jQuery(data).html(); but tmp == null !!! is here. Data does have value (throw new Error(data) all html data in stack)

Comment: hi Val, does the fiddle work on your version of Opera? Can you post the content of your 'data' or provide a fiddle, might have another idea.